# Toggle between hiding and showing an element with JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

```
enter code here
```

> this my form.html it is invoked from smartphone division which is in modal.html form.html is working perfectly fine , there is a problem with modal.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form action="mailto:sayalikanase1910@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="To">To:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="To" valu="sayalikanase1910@gmail.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="From">From:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="From" placeholder="Enter Your Phone No.">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:100px; width :100%;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%; background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;">Send</button>
          
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> modal.html I created small hover sidenavbar button but By clicking on Text us now button div named "smartphone" is not appearing that division contain bootstrap device look which contains form which is invoked from form.html

```css
#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute; 
  right: -80px;
  transition: 0.3s; 
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
 }

 #mySidenav a:hover {
  right : 0;
 }


 #about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
 }

  /* The device with borders */
.smartphone {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 16px black solid;
  border-top-width: 60px;
  border-bottom-width: 60px;
  border-radius: 36px;
}

/* The device with borders */
.smartphone {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 16px black solid;
  border-top-width: 60px;
  border-bottom-width: 60px;
  border-radius: 36px;
}

/* The horizontal line on the top of the device */
.smartphone:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* The circle on the bottom of the device */
.smartphone:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -65px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* The screen (or content) of the device */
.smartphone .content {
  width: 360px;
  height: 640px;
  background: white;
}
.smartphone{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Text Me Now Demo</h2>
<p>In this example, I given a short demo of my work</p>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a id="about" onclick="myFunction" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>Text Us Now</a>
</div> 

<div class="smartphone">
  <div class="content">
    <iframe src="form.html" style="width:100%;border:none;height:100%"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("smartphone");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of attribute is `valu`

Comment: sorry, It's typing mistake i changed it from valu to value still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Change your anchor to `onclick="myFunction()"` with brackets after the function, and use `document.querySelector()` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName()`, so  `var x = document.querySelector(".smartphone");`

Updated body:

```
<body>

<h2>Text Me Now Demo</h2>
<p>In this example, I given a short demo of my work</p>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a id="about" onclick="myFunction()" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>Text Us Now</a>
</div> 

<div class="smartphone">
  <div class="content">
    <iframe src="form.html" style="width:100%;border:none;height:100%"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".smartphone");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much for your help. I tried your solution but it's not working.